# Windows 10 computer causes router to fully reset

Tags: networking, windows-10, anti-virus, wireshark, adsl-router

Last year I had a similar problem, I had posted a ticket about it:

[Windows 10 computer causes router to reset constantly](https://superuser.com/questions/970777/windows-10-computer-causes-router-to-reset-constantly)

This was with a notebook and we could not find a solution to it. Several local techs helped and nobody could figure it out. At that time we just reinstalled Windows 8.1 on that notebook and the problem was resolved.

Now we have a new windows 10 computer, we need to use windows 10 and we're experiencing a similar problem.

The problem is that when this computer is turned on, it causes the adsl modem lights to go off (all lights including power), then it tries to reconnect, then it goes off again. Sometimes at a point we're lucky and it stays on. Sometimes it is necessary to reboot this computer one or more times until the adsl modem stays connected.

When the Win 10 computer is off, Android phones and a Win 7 computer use the internet connection without any issues.

Then during the day, this computer causes router to reset several times.

I will list what we have tried so far after endless research. Maybe anyone can find a solution.

1) The problem started after we enabled windows update service. For some reason the service was initially off in the computer. After updates were installed, the problem begun. Now it does not matter if we turn Windows Update service on or off. As if something related to having installed updates affected it. The anniversary update has been installed.

2) I found someone with a similar problem saying that a reboot of the computer helps. Generally when we initially boot up the computer, it breaks the internet connection (all router lights go off). Rebooting helps most of the time.

3) I found someone saying that reinstalling the antivirus resolved his problem. The computer came with Avira installed and it was configured to auto update every 2 hours. I removed Avira, installed Avast which I am more used to, and set it to ask me before installing updates. This helped reduce the times the computer resets the router during the day. For now.

Note (in case is helps someone think of what may be causing this): when we had the problem with the notebook a year ago, we uninstalled avast and then installed it again, switching from free to paid, and it seemed to solve the problem. After some days the problem restarted. We then uninstalled paid and reinstalled free. It again resolved for a few days. So I think that *something* in the relationship between the Win 10 and the antivirus could be the cause. But I have not idea what it could be. In the case of this new Win 10 desktop, installing Avast only resolved the issue for about 6 hours.

4) I disabled ipv6 protocol and Receive Side Scaling on the adapter. These doesn't seem to have helped.

5) I installed Wireshark to monitor traffic. I have saved several wireshark files. But they contain a lot of output and I am not sure what to look at. I have tried to compare wireshark output when the router is resetting, and when it is online ok, to detect differences. But there are so many records that I am not finding something specific. I could paste parts of the wireshark file here if anyone tells me what could be relevant. The files have thousands of lines.

The adsl modem is ZyXEL P-660HW-T1 v3 provided by my ISP, and the computer is connected with an ethernet cable. I even sent an email to Zyxel from their website but received no response so far. I cannot access the router configuration because the ISP doesn't give me the password, and their support team is useless, I feel as if I was speaking to a concrete wall.

The only way I can get the router replaced by another model is by changing to a higher priced plan. That has been their answer regarding changing the router because it is several years old. Since it works well when this computer is off, they don't think it is their problem.

I would change to the higher priced plan if I knew it will resolve the issue. But I have no certainties.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this computer connecting thru Wi-Fi or via Ethernet? Have you tried both?

Comment: This computer connects via Ethernet. It doesn't have a wifi adapter. Last year with the notebook we tried both ethernet and wifi and it made no difference. Thanks.

Comment: How old is this ADSL router? Honestly, it could just be the age of the poor thing.

Comment: It is five years old. I went to check the original box it came in. It also says (in case it helps):

Comment: FW Ver: 3.70 (TSU.0)
HW Ver: 81-004-870001

Thanks

Comment: This question sounds interesting. If you can get a Wireshark network trace which captures this issue, I'd be happy to take a look over it. Feel free to email me: markopolo.stackexchange@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks for your help! We finally got the ISP to come change the adsl modem. That was two days ago and no more issues after that. So it was something related to the ZyXEL modem.

Comment: For the record: I have the same issue with Windows, but also with a Sonos system. Updating a Sonos Roam SL will make the router reset. So I don't think it's Windows fault...

Comment: Worked around the issue by disabling the 5 Ghz band and the guest network on the router. YMMV.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've just battled this issue for 4 days. Replacing the modem with the same model didn't help, I assume there was a bug in the firmware. Replacing the modem with a different model from the ISP has fixed the issue for me (probably running a different firmware)